# MySQL - JSON - return attribute where value equal true

Tags: mysql, json

I have something like this in my table "superheroes":

```
name   | attributes
Batman | {"dead": false, "orphan": true, "billionaire": true, "goodboy" : true}
```

how can I return all attributes that are true?

I know how to retrieve the value of specific attribute such as

```
select json_extract((SELECT attributes from superheroes where name = 'Batman'),'$.orphan')
```

this will return true, which is correct. But I need to find all attributes that are true. Is there a way in MySQL?This is just example, but real situation is little bit too much complicated...  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest to what you want is [`JSON_SEARCH()`](http://rextester.com/UVMOW45665)

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(attributes, 'all', 'true')
FROM superheroes
WHERE name = 'Batman';
```

However, for this to work, the values have to be strings, not booleans, because `JSON_SEARCH` treats the search string as a `LIKE` pattern to match against strings, not a JSON value. So the JSON has to be:

```
{"dead": "false", "orphan": "true", "billionaire": "true", "goodboy" : "true"}
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/UVMOW45665)

Comment: THANKS! It works and it is exactly what I need. P.S: I have 106 attributes that can be true/false so you saved me, dear Batman... I mean Barmar...